# How a list can be added to another list in c#?

Tags: c#, list, itemssource

I have a page with multiple `listViews`. I have created some difference lists from `DbModels` and need to bind these lists to the `ListViews`. Here what I want is `if (Particulars == Constants.TAG_OPENING_STOCK)` a list adds to a    `ItemsTradingDebitList` list.

and `if(Particulars == Constants.TAG_PURCHASE)` another list should add to  `ItemsTradingCreditList` list.

I have tried creating a new list with values and added it to another list using `AddRange`. But this brings an error `Object Reference not set to an instance of an object.` `list was empty`

```
if (Particulars == Constants.TAG_OPENING_STOCK)
{
    List<string> NewList = new List<string> { Particulars, Amount };
    ItemsTradingDebitList.AddRange(NewList);              
}
if(Particulars == Constants.TAG_PURCHASE)
{
    List<string> NewList = new List<string> { Particulars, Amount };
    ItemsTradingDebitList.AddRange(NewList);
}
if(Particulars == Constants.TAG_SALES)
{
    List<string> NewList = new List<string> { Particulars, Amount };
    ItemsTradingCreditList.AddRange(NewList);
}
```

My expected result is a list of all added lists. What I am getting is an error

Comment: Please, show definition of ItemsTradingDebitList variable and how do you create a new instance of it. Seems ItemsTradingDebitList was not created....

Comment: Did you ever create an instance of `ItemsTradingDebitList`? Before any of this, try adding in `var ItemsTradingDebitList = new List<string>();`

Comment: @HoneyBadger Sorry it was a mistake

Comment: @JohnBustos Yeah I do have a declaration for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe "Particulars", "Amount" are strings, if both are strings, then you can directly add it to the list, here no need to create new list

something like,

```
ItemsTradingDebitList.Add("Amount");    
ItemsTradingDebitList.Add("Particulars");
```

As per error mentioned in question, I guess you have not initialized list i.e. `ItemsTradingDebitList`. If that is the case then before first if condition create an instance of `ItemsTradingDebitList`

like

```
List<string> ItemsTradingDebitList = new List<string>();
```

This will resolve your problem,

```
List<string> ItemsTradingDebitList = new List<string>(); //This might be missing in your code
if (Particulars == Constants.TAG_OPENING_STOCK)
{
    ItemsTradingDebitList.Add("Amount");    
    ItemsTradingDebitList.Add("Particulars");   
}
if(Particulars == Constants.TAG_PURCHASE)
{
    ItemsTradingDebitList.Add("Amount");    
    ItemsTradingDebitList.Add("Particulars"); 
}
if(Particulars == Constants.TAG_SALES)
{
    ItemsTradingDebitList.Add("Amount");    
    ItemsTradingDebitList.Add("Particulars"); 
}
```

Comment: I have declared the list above the code but didn't post here. I declared it as           
 `public List<string> ItemsTradingDebitList = null;`  Should I use `new List<string>();` instead of `null`

Comment: oppp, You need to initialize List as I showed in my answer.. `List<string> ItemsTradingDebitList = new List<string>();`

Comment: If it works then please accept answer by green tick

Comment: @Prasas Telkikar Done.

Answer (score 0):

@prasad-telkikar answer is correct. I just wanted to add a few remarks on your code.

it looks like `Constants.TAG_OPENING_STOCK` and `Constants.TAG_PURCHASE` are well... constants. Probably declared as

```
public static class Constants
{
    public const string TAG_OPENING_STOCK = "TAG_something";
    //...
}
```

So you can improve your code by using a `switch` instead:

```
var ItemsTradingDebitList = new List<string>() ;
switch (Particulars)
{
    case Constants.TAG_OPENING_STOCK:
        // ...
        break;

    case Constants.TAG_PURCHASE:
        // ...
        break;

    // etc.
}
```

If they are not constant but `static readonly string` instead then you can't use them in the switch and can use a series of `if { } else { }` instead.